# How long does it take for a tailed beast to come back after its container is killed?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, how long does it take for a tailed beast to come back after its container is killed? Does it ever specify on how long it takes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'come back'?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who it is, when they die their chakra is disperesed all throughout the world, and eventually recollects, so it would take Shukaku less time than Kurama because he has less chakra.